# imitate viewstate in asp.net mvc with pseudo hidden fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an template_application_area where the user can load a template.

A template can have multiple units.

The units are displayed in a tree control.

While the user can add units like children/siblings to the unit tree I need to know the

templateId when I call the

```
 unitService.AddUnit(string unitName,int templateId);
```

My idea is when the template is opened I save the templateId temporarely in a DIV

(display:none) within the template_application_area so I can grab the templateId when I do my

jquery.ajax addUnit(..) call.

What do you think about this kind of "hidden field" in an asp.net mvc application?

Is my approach fine or are there better ways?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. If you want to persist the value between posts, you can stick it in a input type=hidden. If you just need it until the page is posted or you call the client script to persist you can stick it in a client script variable.

Comment: Yes persist value(s) between posts and after the posts the value should still remain in the template_application_area until the user enters another xxx_application_area. What is the difference of input type hidden vs. a div with display:none? more common approach from webforms?

Comment: Inputs of the type hidden represent values not intended to be examined or manipulated by users. Divs are generic flow containers, used for layout.

Comment: ok thank you. I think thats correct.